# How to add an extra textfield when user clicks on a button?

Tags: html, css, button, input, textfield

I have this code

`<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Author...">`

I want a button and when I click on it, it should show this textfield and the button should disappear.

Comment: Please read before asking questions as you are new to stackoverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Javascript / jquery for that.There are so many ways for doing that.
Here is an example with jquery

```js
$('#button').click(function(){

 $(this).hide();
 
   var html ='<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Author...">'
  
  $('#holder').html(html);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="holder">


</div>


<button id="button">Cick to add textbox</button>
```

Another method using `hide` and `show`

```js
$('#button').click(function(){ 
   $(this).hide(); 
   $('#holder').show();
   
})
```

```css
#holder{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="holder">
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Author...">
  <select>
      <option>Test</option>
      <option>Test</option>
      <option>Test</option>
      <option>Test</option>
  </select>
</div>


<button id="button">Cick to add textbox</button>
```

You can learn more about javascript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web)

Comment: Thanks, where do I add the first code on my HTML page?

Comment: @Yoni you can add this at the bottom of your page inside the <script></script> tag

Comment: Thanks. How can I add an extra dropdown menu in the <script> tag? So I got a dropdown menu and a textfield with the same button

Comment: Yoni you mean select?

Comment: I mean the same as the original question, but then for a dropdown menu instead of for a input field

Comment: @Yoni check the second snippet.you can do like that.hide the dropdown code and the show that on button click.In second snippet i have added a selectbox

Comment: Where do I add #holder{
  display:none;
}

Comment: @Yoni inside the <style></style> tag. inside the <head></head>

Answer (score 1):

```
You may do this simply by using AngularJS. Here is a short example.
```

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
            app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.a=1;
$scope.b=null;
$scope.check=function(){
$scope.a=null;
$scope.b=1;
            }});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
        <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <div ng-show="a"><button ng-click="check()">Click</button></div>
            <div ng-show="b"><input></div>
          </div>
        </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<input class="input" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Author...">
<button class="btn" type="button">
  click
</button>
```

CSS:

```
.input {
  display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
    $('.input').show();
  $(this).hide();
})
```

working example: https://jsfiddle.net/n05reomv/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>

function next(){

document.getElementById("text").hidden=false;
document.getElementById("addBtn").hidden=true;

}
 </script> 

<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Author..." id="text" hidden="true">
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="next()" id="addBtn">
```